# How to find numbers that occur more than once in a list using clojure

Tags: clojure

I have a list of numbers 2 4 3 7 4 9 8 5 12 24 8.

I need to find numbers which are repeated more than once in clojure.

I have used `frequencies` function to find. But the result is

```
{2 1,4 2,3 1,7 1,9 1,8 2,5 1,12 1,24 1}
```

I intially thought of considering them as `key value` and then take each key value once and see if val is > 1. if value is greater than 1 then I need to inc 1.

But I am unable to work this out.

Can anyone please help me??

Is there anyway I can make this into `[[2 1][4 2][3 1][7 1][9 1][8 2][5 1][12 1][24 1]]` and consider each vector recursively or any better idea you can think of.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function below will just continue on where you have stuck:

```
(defn find-duplicates [numbers]
  (->> numbers
       (frequencies)
       (filter (fn [[k v]] (> v 1)))
       (keys)))
```

It will filter map entries that have values greater than 1 and then extract their keys.

```
(find-duplicates [2 4 3 7 4 9 8 5 12 24 8])
;; => (4 8)
```

Answer (score 2):

`(->> s  (group-by identity)  (filter (comp next val))  keys)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the repeated items:

```
(defn repeated [coll]
  (->> coll
       frequencies
       (remove #(= 1 (val %)))
       keys))

(repeated [2 4 3 7 4 9 8 5 12 24 8])
;(4 8)
```

If you just want to count them:

```
(defn repeat-count [coll]
  (->> coll
       frequencies
       (remove #(= 1 (val %)))
       count))

(repeat-count [2 4 3 7 4 9 8 5 12 24 8])
;2
```

You can do it lazily, so that it will work on an endless sequence:

```
(defn repeated [coll]
  ((fn ff [seen xs]
     (lazy-seq
      (when-let [[y & ys] (seq xs)]
        (case (seen y)
         ::several (ff seen ys)
         ::once (cons y (ff (assoc seen y ::several) ys))
         (ff (assoc seen y ::once) ys)))))
   {} coll))

(repeated [2 4 3 7 4 9 8 5 12 24 8])
;(4 8)
```

This is similar to core `distinct`.

---

... and finally, for brevity, ...

```
(defn repeated [coll]
  (for [[k v] (frequencies coll) :when (not= v 1)] k))
```

---

I stole the use of `keys` from [Piotrek Byzdyl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41682956/1562315). It is only supposed to apply to a map. but works perfectly well here on a sequence of map-entries.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

If you seq over hash-map, e. g. via map, you get the kv tuple structure you described and can destructure an individual tuple in the element transformation function:

```
(->> s
     (frequencies)
     (map (fn [[number times]]
            (cond-> number           ; take number
              (> times 1) (inc)))))  ; inc if (times > 1), otherwise return number
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach.

```
(def c [2 4 3 7 4 9 8 5 12 24 8])

(->> c
     sort
     (partition-by identity)
     (filter #(> (count %) 1))
     (map first))
```

Comment: It's good but computationally more expensive, to achieve the same computational complexity as other solutions you can choose `group-by` without `sort` (which is `O(nlogn)`)